# Gembox spreadsheet : Is it possible to apply "Convert To Number" for the cells with warning?

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I am trying set my formatted datatable to an excel worksheet.

Simply :

```
ws.InsertDataTable(myDatatable,
new InsertDataTableOptions()
{
    ColumnHeaders = false,
    StartRow = 5
});
```

But myDatatable cells contains numeric values mostly.
And when I insert my datatable into excel via Gembox Spreadsheet, many of the cells got "Number Stored as Text" warning.

I don't want to disable this warning, but I want to apply a "Convert To Number" as we do in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that those numeric values in `myDatatable` are of `string` type, am I right?
In that case try the following:

```
var options = new InsertDataTableOptions()
{
    ColumnHeaders = false,
    StartRow = 5
};

options.DataTableCellToExcelCellConverting += (s, e) =>
{
    string textNumber = e.DataTableValue as string;
    double number;
    if (textNumber != null && double.TryParse(textNumber, out number))
        e.ExcelCellValue = number;
};

ws.InsertDataTable(myDatatable, options);
```